# Android - App locale changes and displayed orientation

Tags: android, configuration, locale, sharedpreferences, android-orientation

I'm having a headache with the locale thing in my app. So basically my app supports two languages, English and Vietnamese, and user can choose to change the language to be displayed. So I have a `SettingActivity` like this:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends SherlockPreferenceActivity implements OnPreferenceChangeListener{
    private ListPreference langPref;
    private SharedPreferences languagepref;
    private String language;
    private Locale locale;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    languagepref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);               
    Configuration config = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
    language = languagepref.getString("languageToLoad","en");
    locale = new Locale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences_login);

    langPref = (ListPreference) findPreference("lang_pref");
    if (language.equalsIgnoreCase("vi")){
        langPref.setValueIndex(1);
    }
    else{
        langPref.setValueIndex(0);
    }
    langPref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}


@Override
public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
    String key = preference.getKey();
    if (key.equals("lang_pref")){
        String languageToLoad  = (String) newValue;
        Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);  
        Locale.setDefault(locale); 
        Configuration config = new Configuration(); 
        config.locale = locale; 
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,  
        getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = languagepref.edit();
        editor.putString("languageToLoad",languageToLoad );
        editor.commit();
        recreate();     
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

In every other activity, I add this in their `onCreate` method:

```
SharedPreferences languagepref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);               
        Configuration config = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
        String language = languagepref.getString("languageToLoad","en");
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        config.locale = locale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

And now my app is acting weird: in the `SettingActivity`, the language is displayed properly whenever I rotate my device, even without the need of adding `android:configChanges="locale"` in the activity's manifest. However, in every other activity, the language is changed back to English when I rotate the device. I've try adding `android:configChanges="locale"` in their manifest but it doesn't work. Also, I've tried every solution found on Stackoverflow but none of them works for me, so I'm basically clueless now. Could anyone of you help me point out the mistake I made here? Please do and thanks in advance.

Comment: instead of using the getBaseContext(), try using the getApplicationContext()

Comment: I've went through a headache with localization myself: http://android-know-how-to.blogspot.co.il/2013/08/multi-language-android-application.html

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden"
```

in the manifest for each activity.

Then you should override onConfigurationChanged in your activities, and in this method reload layout (depending orientation). If you still have problems with locale, reload the appropriate locale in onConfigurationChanged.

Comment: I'm sorry but what do you mean by 'reload layout' specifically?

Comment: if you use a different xml layout for landscape and portrait, when orientation change you have to change the layout for your activity (with setContentView for example). If you use the sam layout, just ignore this, and focus on your "locale" problem.